# JMX MBean - synchronized on getters and setters

Tags: java, thread-safety, jmx

I just want to clarify my understanding about the thread-safety of a JMX MBean.

I have a simple MBean like so:

```
public class Person
    implements PersonMBean
{
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

On the condition that there can be multiple clients accessing the MBean (for example, multiple users call setName() via jconsole), I do need need to synchronize the getter and setter, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... there can be multiple clients call[ing] setName() via jconsole, do I need need to synchronize the getter and setter?

Yes, you probably should if multiple threads are calling the getters and setters -- just like you should if multiple local threads are calling the getter and setter.  As @user454322 pointed out, using the `volatile` keyword to accomplish the memory synchronization is also appropriate.

Synchronization of some form is necessary for two reasons.  Firstly, multiple JMX operations can be running at the same time meaning that getter and setter race-conditions can happen.  Secondly, even if the setter happens before the getter, there is no guarantee that the JMX thread has the updated value without synchronization.  It depends on how important it is that each thread gets the last value of the name.  If all threads must see the very last name that was set, then you'll need to keep things well `synchronized`.

This said, we have a lot of unsynchronized JMX getter methods on statistics and other diagnostic information and expect that the JVM will synchronize the various counters at some point.

Comment: Just to clarify, making the methods `synchronized` *won't* stop race conditions between multiple threads (assuming the methods are simple field accessors/mutators).  The calling code would need to `synchronize` on the object to ensure that, something that can't (as far as I know) be done via JMX.

Comment: Synchronizing on the object (I assume you mean the argument to the setter) won't matter either since the object is a serialized RMI argument @SimonC.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization might not be what you need. Synchronization defines a *happens-before* relation, which I think is not necessary here.
So

```
volatile private String name;
```

might be enough.

If *happens-before* really matters, I would go with a [fair reentrant lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#ReentrantLock%28boolean%29).

From *[JLS 3 8.3.1.4 volatile Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.3.1.4)*

> The Java programming language provides a second mechanism [besides synchronization], volatile
>   fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes.

This might be one of those purposes.

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java memory model
>   (§17) ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the
>   variable.

Anyway look at *[17.4.5 Happens-before Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.4.5)* in JLS and decide what is best for you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If all your JMX bean is doing is setting the value of a field, then all you would need to do is declare the field as `volatile`.  This ensures that subsequent reads to the variable see the previous writes.

Making the methods `synchronized` also gives the same guarantees, but with the additional cost of obtaining a monitor.